# how to load a properties file with non-ascii in ant

Tags: ant

Suppose I have a properties file test.properties, which saved using utf-8

```
 testOne=测试
```

I am using the following ant script to load it and echo it to another file:

```
 <loadproperties srcFile="test.properties" encoding="utf-8"/>
 <echo encoding="utf-8" file="text.txt">${testOne}</echo>
```

When I open the generated text.txt file using "utf-8" encoding I see:

```
 ??
```

What's wrong with my script?

Comment: What editor were you using and what platform are you on? It could very well be that your editor isn't using UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Use "encoding" and "escapeunicode" together. It's work fine.

```
<loadproperties srcfile="${your.properties.file}" encoding="UTF-8">
    <filterchain>
        <escapeunicode />
    </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work around, but I still doesn't understand why the org one doesn't work:

```
<native2ascii src="." dest=".">
<mapper type="glob" from="test.properties" to="testASCII.properties"/>
</native2ascii>
<loadproperties srcFile="testASCII.properties"/>
```

Then the echo works as expected.

I don't know why the encoding in loadproperties doesn't work.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: `<native2ascii>` is translating your source file into ASCII with escaped Unicode characters. My property file is converted to `testOne=\u6d4b\u8bd5`. Ant will then display the correctly escaped utf-8 character codes. I'll have to look at how Ant handles encodings to see why it can't display native encoded characters.

Comment: Okay: It's not a _Ant bug_, it's a _Java Feature_. [Properties files in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) must be encoded with ISO 8859-1 character encoding. See the second line of the fourth paragraph). As it says _The native2ascii tool can be used to convert property files to and from other character encodings_.

Comment: Then in loadproperties task there should not be a parameter called "encoding" right? It has encoding parameter but doesn't really do the job that's why I think it is a bug in Ant.

Comment: I'll have to look at the source code. Good question what the encoding parameter does. I wonder if it has to do with the other types resources. I believe `<loadproperties>` is probably derived from `<loadresources>` and encoding may work there.

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
<loadproperties srcfile="non_ascii_property.properties">
  <filterchain>
    <escapeunicode/>
  </filterchain>
</loadproperties>
```

Apparently, InputStreamReader that uses the ISO Latin-1 charset, which kills your non-ascii characters.  I ran into the same issue w/Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

What editor were you using and what platform are you on?

Your generated property file might actually be good, but the editor you're using to examine it may be incapable of viewing it. For example, on my Mac, the `VIM` command line editor can view it (which surprises me), but in Eclipse, it looks like this:

```
testOne=������
```

If you're on Unix/Linux/Mac, try using [od](http://man.cx/od) to dump your generated file, and examine the actual hex code to see what it should be.

For example, I copied your property file, and ran `od` on a Mac:

```
$ od -t x1 -t c test.property
0000000    74  65  73  74  4f  6e  65  3d  e6  b5  8b  e8  af  95  0a    
           t   e   s   t   O   n   e   =  测  **  **  试  **  **  \n
```

Here I can see that the code for `测` is `36 b5 8b` and `试` is `e8  af  95` which is the correct UTF-8 representation for these two characters. (Or, I at least think so. It shows up correctly in the Character Viewer Mac OS X panel).

Comment: I think it is a bug in Ant. See my own answer

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is pointed to in this comment by *David W.*:

[how to load a properties file with non-ascii in ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7720659/how-to-load-a-properties-file-with-non-ascii-in-ant#comment30599398_7734746)

**Java Property Files must be encoded in `ISO-8859-1`**:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

But **Unicode escape sequences like `\u6d4b` can/must be used to encode unicode characters therein**.

**Tools/ANT-Targets like `<native2ascii>`**, generating ascii-encoded files from natively maintained ones, **can help here**.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own task that reads properties from your default java character encoding for your OS (mine is utf-8), instead of converting your property files to unreadable unicode-escaped ASCII files (designed by people who read and write only English).  Here's how to do it by copying and modifying Property.java from Ant's source code to your own package (e.g. org.my.ant).  I used Ant 1.10.1.

Download Ant's source code in your format of choice from here:
http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi

Copy src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Property.java to your own project (such as a new Java project), in org/my/ant/Property.java)

replace:

```
package org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs;
```

with:

```
package org.my.ant;
```

Fix any imports needed by the package change.  I just needed to add:

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute;
```

In the method:

```
loadProperties(Properties props, InputStream is, boolean isXml)
```

replace:

```
props.load(is);
```

with:

```
props.load(new InputStreamReader(is));
```

In your project's resources folder (could be the same as your source folder), add the file org/my/ant/antlib.xml, with the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<antlib>

<taskdef name="property" classname="org.my.ant.Property"/>

</antlib>
```

Compile this project (Property.java + antlib.xml).

Put the resulting jar in Ant's classpath, as explained here:
http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#external-tasks

Then use it in a build.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="example"
    xmlns:my="antlib:org.my.ant"
    default="print"
    >

    <my:property file="greek.properties" prefix="example" />

    <target name="print">
        <echo message="${example.a}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

The file greek.properties contains:

```
a: ΑΒΓ
```